# The WETH / 4 2.0 pair already has liqudity on Uniswap V2. You cannot create a presale for this pair as the price is already set

Tags: contract-development

The WETH / 4 2.0 pair already has liqudity on Uniswap V2.
You cannot create a presale for this pair as the price is already set. So how do I get my tax token to market, And if my token or contract fails on unicrypts presale how do I get it to market.

Thank you